# Trying to dismiss react-native modal when clicking outside of the box

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am able to currently dismiss the modal when clicking outside of the box, but the issue is that when I click inside the box it still dismisses. I have tried adding `pointerEvents="none"`, which does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<View>
          <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            style={{width: '100%', alignSelf: 'center', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor:'green'}}
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              alert('Modal has been closed.');
            }}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
              this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
            }}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1}} >

                <View pointerEvents="none" style={{alignSelf: 'center', width: '80%', height: '50%', backgroundColor: 'purple', top: 100}}>
                  <Text pointerEvents="none" >Hello World!</Text>


                </View>

            </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Modal>
        </View>
```

Comment: This is because you're setting this `onPress={() => {
              this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
            }}` yourself

Comment: what is the workaround then?

Comment: `onPress={() => {}}` , or set it in some cross button of the modal, not on the wrapper

Comment: Try adding `pointerEvents="box-only"` to the `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

Comment: My goal is for the wrapper to be dismissible, but the contents (the box with the text) should not be dismissible.

Comment: adding pointerEvents="box-only" did not do the trick. @MattAft

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { modalVisible: true }
  }
  setModalVisible(modalVisible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          style={{ width: '100%', alignSelf: 'center', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'green' }}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
          }}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1 }} >
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { }}>
                <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: '80%', height: '50%', backgroundColor: 'purple', top: 100 }}>
                  <Text>Hello World!</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});a
```

Comment: I have tested again and it worked for me. For your reference i have added whole code.

Comment: This works but then my horizontal FlatList inside the modal is not responding to touch events. If I didn't have scrollable content, this would have been a perfect fit for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

So I got it to work, which will only work with the react-native-modal. The modal that ships with react does not work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

`Modal` component provided by React Native doesn't provide many options to control it's behavior. I suggest you try [react-native-community/react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This way solved for me by using [react-native-community/react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) and state to manage the visibility.
And properties `onBackdropPress` will be work. For elements to trigger the modal, you should set the state to true. See the code below

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  isVisible:false
}

<Modal
  isVisible       = {this.state.isVisible}
  onBackdropPress = { () => this.setState({isVisible:false})}
  backdropOpacity = {0.3}
  style           = {styles.modal}>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Setting the state directly from the Onpress event worked for me. that is instead of using this:

     <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
    
    You can change  to :
    
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
            this.setState({modalVisible:false})}}>
```